# Does Thirsting Blade from Eldritch invocations stack with multi attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, lycanthropy

My DM is open to odd characters and is letting me play a true lycanthropy weretiger in DnD 5e. We went over the entry in the monster manual for [weretiger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/weretiger) and decided what modifications should be made.

He told me to include the multiattack feature and I believe to ignore the specificity of weapons (though I'm sure exclusions should still apply to say 2 handed melee weapons and heavy weapons). He was fully aware that I would be playing the warlock class and taking the pact of the blade.

My question is, if I take the Eldritch invocation [thirsting blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388), will that stack with multiattack?

> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

If so, will I attack twice for both of those attacks giving me 4 physical attacks per turn at times?

Comment: Yes I think that answers it quite well. Should I delete this question or just mark it as answered?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is 100% a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is asking about how the multiattack feature of a creature stacks with the general attack action. This question is asking how the multiattack feature interacts with a specialized class feature. They're *highly* related, but not duplicates in my eyes.

Comment: Mark it as answered please so that it can act as a signpost for others to find that question. :)

Comment: @ThomasMaltuin No, duplicates are useful because they can redirect others searching for the same thing to the correct answer.

Comment: @Rykara I can see what you mean, but still don’t really think there’s much of a value in having it as a separate question.

Comment: @Rykara The target is asking about Extra Attack -which is identical to Thirsting blade in all but name - and Multiattack, but also includes a misunderstanding of how Extra Attack works (which is why it is asking about using the attack action twice).